# SSH url without user

Tags: git, ssh, git-submodules

we are setting up a git project with several submodules and several users. All users have ssh access to the git repos.

The submodules get updated fine for **userA**.
The problem is that the url in the `.gitmodules` file is   *ssh://**user**A@server:port/submodule.location.git* format (git submodule command added like that).

Therefore when **userB** clones the repo and tires to update the submodules, the url will still be **userA**... so the clone will fail.

Tried to remove the username, `ssh://server:port/location.git` but it still fails with publickey error.

How should we approach this?
What format should I use so that git always substitutes the current user?

Thank you.

Comment: If you try to `git clone ssh://server:port/location.git` as userB, without it being a submodule, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to switch to the `git://` protocol. This protocol is ssh protocol which use the ssh key to identify the user and you dont need to use username.

for example this is a sample from github:

```
git@github.com:...
```

As you can see you don't have any username in the URL (if you will have any its the user who created the repo and the user who clone)

Switch to the [***`git protocol`***](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol) and you will not have to set any user in the url. simply create keys add it to your server and that it.